# Increase performance of HLS audio conversion with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg command line tool to convert a lot of audio files (mp3) into HLS-format. The requirements is that all mp3-files should be converted into one m3u8-file and the ts-files and that there is a crossfade effect overlapping each track.

Currently my script looks like below:

```
ffmpeg 
  -i 1.mp3 
  -i 2.mp3 
  -i 3.mp3 
  -i 4.mp3 
  -y 
  -filter_complex [0][1]acrossfade=d=5:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01];[a01][2]acrossfade=d=5:c1=tri:c2=tri[a12];[a12][3]acrossfade=d=5:c1=tri:c2=tri 
  -acodec aac -b:a 96k 
  -vn 
  -ac 2 
  -f segment 
  -segment_format mpegts 
  -segment_time 10 
  -segment_list_type m3u8 
  -segment_list manifest.m3u8 segment-%05d.ts
```

This takes about 5.2 seconds for each input so in this case about 21 seconds but doing it for 100 tracks takes more than 8 minutes and so on. Is there some performance improvements that can be done here? I would like this to go faster, I guess that the other options than the required ones could be altered if that speeds things up.

Comment: What's the process speed at the end (`speed=`) ?

Comment: seems to be 102x

Comment: No easy way to speed this up.